# Pasar variable GET y tomar datos sin recargar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, paginación

buenas tardes a todos. Les comento, estoy creando un blog y tengo un problema trabajando con la paginacion de mi sitio.
Como estoy pasando por get la variable de  la pagina en la que me encuentro, mi sitio se recarga asi que los estilos de mi paginacion nunca cambia (Siempre mantiene el primer elemento como active)

Les voy compartiendo y comentando el codigo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pageItem = $('.pagination li').not('.prev,.next');
  var prev = $('.pagination li.prev');
  var next = $('.pagination li.next');

  prev.addClass('disabled');
  pageItem.first().addClass('active');

  pageItem.click(function () {
    pageItem.removeClass('active');
    $(this).not('.prev,.next').addClass('active');

    if ($(this).next().hasClass('next')) {
      next.addClass('disabled');
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    }

    if ($(this).prev().hasClass('prev')) {
      prev.addClass('disabled');
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  next.click(function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

    if (next.prev().hasClass('active')) {
      next.addClass('disabled');
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      prev.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  prev.click(function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');

    if (prev.next().hasClass('active')) {
      prev.addClass('disabled');
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      next.removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.pagination li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #7c3c01;
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.disabled a span {
  color: #000000;
}
.active {
  background-color: #e99d57;
  color: #633001;
}
.pagination li:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #f0b680;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="prev">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Anterior">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!--
            <?php
            Este es mi codigo php para traer las entradas de la db
            // PAGINACION
            $total_art = mysqli_num_rows($entradas);
            $art_x_page = 4;
            $pages = ceil($total_art / $art_x_page);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?pagina=<?= $i + 1; ?>"><?= $i + 1; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endfor; 
            
            Para mostrar los estilos agregare li estaticos
            ?>
            -->
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </li>

            <li class="next">
                <a href="#" aria-label="Siguiente">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Vean que mis estilos cambian perfectamente, pero cuando les paso la variable de  la pagina, la misma se recarga y siempre me muestra el primer elemento como active...

No se si hay alguna manera de pasar la variable y actualizar la pagina sin recargar o de modificar los estilos una vez recargada la pagina, este proyecto lo estoy haciendo lo mas vanilla posible, como libreria solo estoy usando JQuery, despues es todo código escrito por mi, asi que acepto cualquier sugerencia. Muchas gracias y quedo a la orden ante cualquier consulta!

Comment: Para que la página no se recargue tendrías que usar Ajax, así podrías mandar/recibir datos del servidor y mostrarlos sin tener que recargar la página en cada envío. Aquí hay varias respuestas que explican cómo funciona Ajax.

Comment: Investigare entonces, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si el problema es que la pagina seleccionada no tiene la clase **active**, entonces podrías tomar los parámetros GET con JavaScript así:

```
var search = location.search.replace("?", "").split("&");

var parametros = {};

for (var x in search) {
    var s = search[x].split("=");

    var indice = s[0];
    var valor = s[1];

    parametros[indice] = valor;
}
```

Ahora a ti te interesa el parámetro GET **pagina**, con el código anterior podrías tomarlo y con ese valor en JQuery podrías agregarle la clase **active**:

```
var pagina = parametros.pagina;

$(".pagination li").eq(pagina).addClass("active");
```

Inclusive puedes hacerlo con PHP sin necesidad de tomar los parámetros GET con JavaScript:

```php
<script>
    var pagina = <?php echo (isset($_GET["pagina"]) ? $_GET["pagina"] : ""); ?>;

    if (pagina) {
        $(".pagination li").eq(pagina).addClass("active");
    }
</script>
```